# Extend a python list to contain all the numbers in between

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list like this:

```
_list=[50,100]
```

Is there a inbuilt function in python which will take a 'step' value and create a new list which will contain all the values after increasing each step.
The new list should look like this:

```
step=2
_list=[50,52,54,56,58,60,62.....100]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use the inbuilt *`range(start,stop[,step])`* function:

```
_list = range(50,101,2)
print _list
#[50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100]
```

*Note : If you wonder why I have put 101 instead of 100, its because the end point is omitted in both `range` and `xrange` functions and also the argument `step` is optional*

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `xrange` function

```
xrange(50, 101, 2)
```

Usage can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) and is as follows:

```
xrange(start, stop[, step])
```

You should use `range` instead of `xrange` if you are not iterating over the list or if you work under Python 3.

Comment: I assumed he was then going to iterate over them, so used xrange instead. Answer modified to take feedback into account.

Comment: Note that in Python 3.x, `range()` gives a special iterable object, which is the best of both worlds, and `xrange()` no longer exists.

Comment: What is the difference between range and xrange?

Comment: Python 2: `xrange()` returns a sequence object which behaves lazily. `range()` creates a list. In Python 3 was `xrange()` _REMOVED_ and `range()` now behaves like `xrange()`.

Comment: @rajat however for your task its `range()` that suits better whereas if you'd use `xrange` you would need more unnecessary code which simply would be the same as using the `range()` function

Answer (score 0):

But this is just list generation using step value, you don't extend a list in this context.

extends is a totally different thing in python with lists
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists